# How to double tap (instead of a single tap) a collection view cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now, I have a bunch of messages in a collectionview cell. 
My code to single tap the cell right now is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Which cell: ", indexPath)
}
```

How do I make it such that this will only print if it is double tapped not single tapped?

Comment: You could use custom cell that response to two taps gesture.

Comment: You can add a tap gesture on cell and ignore the `didSelectItemAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UITapGestureRecognizer in collection view.

```
  private var doubleTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    func setUpDoubleTap() {
        doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDoubleTapCollectionView))
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
        doubleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    }
```

Call above method from your **viewDidLoad** as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpDoubleTap()
    }
```

Then add Gesture selector method in your class

```
 @objc func didDoubleTapCollectionView() {
        let pointInCollectionView = doubleTapGesture.location(in: collectionView)
        if let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: pointInCollectionView) {
            let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
            // Print double tapped cell's path
            print("Which cell: ", selectedIndexPath.row)
            print(" double tapped")
        }
    }
```

**didDoubleTapCollectionView** method will call only when you will double tap on collection view cell item.

I hope above example will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
    let tapCell = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doubleTap(selectedIndex:)))
    tapCell.numberOfTapsRequired=2
    cell.tag=indexPath.row
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapCell)
    return cell
}

@objc func doubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("Selected Index Is", gesture.view?.tag)
}
```

Comment: Please do not use "didSelected Method" this code copy into "doubleTap"

Comment: @Jamin You don't need to use tag. `gesture.view` is `cell` itself.